# Getting JSON exchange rate from fixer.io to HTML

Tags: html, json, fixer.io

I'm trying to get the current USD to EUR rate from fixer.io into a single line in a HTML file and replace the "." in the USD value with a ",".

Can somebody help me?

LINK: https://api.fixer.io/latest?symbols=USD

```
{
  "base": "EUR",
  "date": "2017-12-04",
  "rates": {
    "USD": 1.1865
  }
}
```

What i need in a HTML file:

```
1,1865
```

EDIT:

This is what i tried so far (literally never done this before):

HTML:

```
<span id="rate_usd"></span>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var url= "https://api.fixer.io/latest?symbols=USD"
  $.getJSON(url,function(data){
    document.getElementById("rate_usd").innerHTML = data.rates.USD;

  });
});
```

Comment: this link will help you [link]https://openexchangerates.github.io/money.js/#basic-install

Comment: I don't know what to do with that. Sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the below, it includes all the HTML, JS and jQuery dependency you were referencing.

You were pretty close, here we are taking the number returned by the API, converting it to a string with `toString()` and then replacing the `.` with `,` as requested.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>USD Rate</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <span id="rate_usd"></span>
    <script
      src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"
      integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4="
      crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script>
      $(function() {
        $.getJSON('https://api.fixer.io/latest?symbols=USD', function(data) {
          var usdRate = data.rates.USD.toString();
          var commaFormatted = usdRate.replace('.', ',')
          document.getElementById('rate_usd').innerHTML = commaFormatted;
        });
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you! Works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Also you can give a try to the Java API for fixer.io:
https://github.com/lico/jFixer

These API encapsulate the call to the web service.